# Trying to run an executable inside of the Program files (x86) directory in a dockerfile throws an error

Tags: docker, steam

I am new to docker. Excuse my ignorance on this topic.

I created a dockerfile with the intent on running the windows steam application. this is my docker file.

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 

ADD https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe c:\SteamSetup.exe
RUN c:\SteamSetup.exe /S

ENTRYPOINT ["c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"]
```

I verified that in the docker image Steam is installed at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe` I attached to the docker with a powershell entrypoint and was able to run `"& c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"` I cannot however get the docker image to launch steam on its own. I gt the error below.

```
PS C:\Users\AJWHEELE\Desktop\dockers\steamOS> docker build -t ajwtech/windowstest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
 ---> 80e84fd280e2
Step 2/4 : ADD https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe c:\SteamSetup.exe
Downloading [==================================================>]  1.574MB/1.574MB

 ---> Using cache
 ---> d39ad50d3754
Step 3/4 : RUN c:\SteamSetup.exe /S
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 33cdd5566dad
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"]
 ---> Running in 65027c59352a
Removing intermediate container 65027c59352a
 ---> e92095819109
Successfully built e92095819109
Successfully tagged ajwtech/windowstest:latest
PS C:\Users\AJWHEELE\Desktop\dockers\steamOS> docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=192.168.1.119:0 ajwtech/windowstest:latest
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
PS C:\Users\AJWHEELE\Desktop\dockers\steamOS>
```

Also I am trying to get Steam to launch so that I can see the user interface. currently I am on a windows 10 machine trying to use VcXsrv.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue try to escape the slashes in the ENTRYPOINT path.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\Steam.exe"]
```